# How to get number of free inodes? (`df -i` equivalent)

Tags: go

Is there a way to check the number of available/used/total inodes on a filesystem in Go?

I want something just like what `df -i` returns, and don't want to call `df` if possible.

Example of `df`:

```
# On macOs 10.15 (-i not needed here)
df /
Filesystem   512-blocks     Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s2  236568496 22038704  44026328    34%  488339 1182354141    0%   /

# On Ubuntu 18.04
df -i /
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda1      2621440 219719 2401721    9% /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [syscall.Statfs](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Statfs). Its arguments are a pathname and a pointer to a *Statfs_t* struct. It fills in the struct with statistics for the filesystem that contains the file or directory specified by the pathname. Typically you'd use `.` or `/` or the pathname of a mount point.

Here's a Go program that takes a pathname as its argument and displays inode information.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    var statfs syscall.Statfs_t
    path := os.Args[1]
    if err := syscall.Statfs(path, &statfs); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Cannot stat %s: %v\n", path, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Inodes: total %d, free %d\n", statfs.Files, statfs.Ffree)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the systems that you mentioned, macOs and Ubuntu, you can use

[`func Fstatfs(fd int, buf *Statfs_t) (err error)`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Fstatfs) .

The input argument [`*unix.Statfs_t`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Statfs_t) would then be updated assuming the `unix.Fstatfs` call doesn't error.

`unix.Statfs_t.Files` and `unix.Statfs_t.Ffree` are total number of inodes and number of free inodes respectively for the filesystem that corresponds to the `fd`, the first arugment of the `unix.Fstatfs` call.

---

See also: [manual of statfs system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statfs.2.html)